# MySQL regexp search json

Tags: mysql, json, regex

In mysql I have this table:

```
id    types_id
1     ["1","2"]
2     ["1","2","3"]
3     ["2","3"]
...
```

I wanna use `REGEXP` to get all rows that contain `"3"` at `types_id` json

Comment: @chris85 Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `regexp` for this, just use `like`.

```
where types_id like '%"3"%'
```